# Динамические выпадающие списки select с пересчетом option

Tags: vue.js

Есть кнопка добавить, после нажатия на которую добавляется новый элемент в таблицу, у которого есть свой номер и выпадающий список `select`.

Как сделать, чтобы после выбора `option`, сам `select` становился неактивным и при создании нового элемента этот `option` был недоступен, так как он уже был выбран в одном из предыдущих элементов.

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addItemHandler">Add item</button>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Items</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(item, index) in listItemsHandler" :key="index">
            <td>{{item.num}}</td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" @change="optionValueHandler($event, item.num)">
                <option v-for="(option, index) in item.options" :key="index" :value="option.name">{{option.title}}</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteItemHandler(item.num)">delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'home',
  data() {
    return {
      num: 0,
      listItems: [],
      optionsDefault: [{
        "name": "france",
        "title": "France",
        "price": 10
      }, {
        "name": "spain",
        "title": "Spain",
        "price": 5
      }, {
        "name": "germany",
        "title": "Germany",
        "price": 30
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    listItemsHandler() {
      return this.listItems;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItemHandler() {
      this.num += 1;
      this.listItems.push({
        num: this.num,
        options: this.optionsDefault,
        disableState: false
      });
    },
    deleteItemHandler(num) {
      let i = this.listItems.map(item => item.num).indexOf(num);
      this.listItems.splice(i, 1)
    },
    optionValueHandler(event, num) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      console.log(num);
      event.target.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** Создайте вычисляемое свойство `selectedOptions` выбранных опций.

**2** Создайте вычисляемое свойство `availableOptions` доступных опций.

**3** Создайте вычисляемое свойство `isHidden` для скрытия опции в выпадающем списке.

**4** Создайте вычисляемое свойство `isDisabled` для блокировки кнопки добавления выпадающих списков.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

const Home = {
  name: 'home',
  data() {
    return {
      num: 0,
      listItems: [],
      optionsDefault: [{
        "name": "france",
        "title": "France",
        "price": 10
      }, {
        "name": "spain",
        "title": "Spain",
        "price": 5
      }, {
        "name": "germany",
        "title": "Germany",
        "price": 30
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // Список выбранных `option`.
    selectedOptions() {
      return this.listItems.map(item => item.country);
    },
    // Список доступных `option`.
    availableOptions() {
      // Если хоть один `option` был уже выбран.
      if (this.selectedOptions.length) {
        // Используем стрелки для поднятия контекста.
        return this.optionsDefault.filter(i => !this.isHidden(i.name));
      } else {
        return this.optionsDefault;
      }
    },
    // Маркер, что переданный `option` надо скрыть.
    isHidden() {
      return (name) => this.selectedOptions.includes(name);
    },
    // Маркер блокировки кнопки добавления выпадающих списков.
    isDisabled() {
      return !this.availableOptions.length;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItemHandler() {
      this.num++;
      this.listItems.push({
        num: this.num,
        country: ''
      });
    },
    updateItemHandler(event, element) {
      // Найдем опцию из списка опций.
      // Имя опции должно соответствовать стране элемента.
      let option = this.optionsDefault.find(item => element.country === item.name);

      // Устанавливаем дополнительные свойства для объекта.
      element.price = option.price
    },
    deleteItemHandler(num) {
      let index = this.listItems.findIndex(item => num === item.num);
      let deleted = this.listItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  template: `
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <button :disabled="isDisabled" @click="addItemHandler" class="btn btn-primary">Add item</button>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>Number</th><th>Items</th><th>Price</th><th></th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item, index) in listItems" :key="index">
          <td>{{ item.num }}</td>
          <td>
            <select v-model="item.country" :disabled="!!item.country"  @change="updateItemHandler($event, item)" class="form-control">
              <template v-for="(option, index) in optionsDefault">
                <option :value="option.name" :hidden="isHidden(option.name)">{{option.title}}</option>
              </template>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteItemHandler(item.num)">delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <pre>Сформированный список {{ listItems }}</pre>
    <pre>Список выбранных option {{ selectedOptions }}</pre>
    <pre>Список доступных option {{ availableOptions }}</pre>
  </div>
</section>`
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'home': Home
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <home />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: можете подсказать пожалуйста если в optionsDefault ещё есть price, как можно вывести в td этого элемента,  после того как был выбран селект. Я добавил в вопросе price

Comment: Да, просто текст, если в селекте мы выбрали germany то в этом tr - должно появиться 30, я не понимаю как можно это нормально сделать

Comment: можете в коде показать я не совсем понимаю куда optionValueHandler вешать, на select ?

Comment: @DimaVleskov, здесь лучше смотреть, где выполнил изменения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/994376/revisions

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно